# How can I shuffle text in a Text View?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, textview

Hey I'm a beginner in Swift and I created a Text View with text and now I want that when I click on the button the text shuffles. First I worked with shuffle() but it can only shuffles text in Arrays. The problem is that text every time could be different. So I can't make an fixed Array. I also tried to make an empty Array and set it on the text, but it failed. How can I shuffle the text in the Text View?

Comment: Post what you’ve tried and where you’re facing the issue.

Comment: Use `String`'s `components(separatedBy: )` to make an array of letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly not the most elegant version but it does what you want it to do:
(Tested on iOS 13.5)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var text = "There will be text"

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            
            Text(self.text)
            
            Button(action: {
                // new empty array. Could also be outside
                var arr: Array<String> = []

                //Split current text at every space
                for s in self.text.split(separator: " ") { 
                    arr.append(String(s)) //append to new array

                    // if length of new array is the length of all substrings
                    if arr.count == self.text.split(separator: " ").count {
                        arr.shuffle()
                        self.text = "" // empty Text field
                        for s in arr {
                            self.text.append(s + " ")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }){
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```